# How I make a htacces for he redirect my application to my subfolder from my domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

Excuse the low english.

I have a zend framework Project and  I need  to upload it in server. But I can’t ssh acces, just ftp. Also there are many projects in public_html (htdocs or www) of server, so my Project needs its own folder.

How I make a htacces for he redirect my application to my subfolder from my domain??

My structure:

```
public_html/.htaccess 

public_html/project/ application
public_html/project/library
public_html/project/public
...
```

thanks!

Comment: is sshd set up on your server? i am just commenting on the "cant access ssh" portion.

Comment: no. I haven't remote acces.

Comment: Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or try if you can use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to make [symlink](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in .htaccess, just replace "YourDomain.com" with your domain and "FolderName" with your website folder name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ FolderName [L]
```

For other information on what you can do with a .htaccess file I recommend the following site:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/